# Pass a method of a specific object as an input argument in Tcl

Tags: oop, tcl, metadata, proc

I am writing an EDA utility, relying on a TCL 8.6 compliant API. My challenge is as follows:
 My utility runs on transistors' models in the database, and does some analyisis, using an EDA vendors' TCL API command. I can pass to the TCL commands a TCL procedure name/pointer, and the analysis will rely on my code, rather than the EDA vendors' code. The in-house written proc accepts as an argument a pointer to the specific transistor's instance in the EDA vendor's database.
Now, the EDA vendor allows for TCL 8.6, which means that I want to pass rather than a global proc name, or a namespace proc name, the name/pointer of the specific object's name. How do I do that? In code example:

```
oo:class create foo {
   constructor {} {
      variable numy 2
   }
   method fooshta { mos_pointer } {
      puts "now in mosy [get name $mos_pointer ]"
   }
   destructor {}
}
foo create bar
analyse_tx -proc < how do I refer to bar's method fooshta?>
```

In a non OOP context, the code would look like:

```
proc fooshta { mos_pointer } {
      puts "now in mosy [get name $mos_pointer ]"
   }
 analyse_tx -proc fooshta
```

As can be seen, I am looking for the answer for  `< how do I refer to bar's method fooshta, so that the EDA tool will invoke it for each transistors' instance? and pass the parameter?>`
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not directly, at least not if it is going to be invoked like this:

```
$procname $thing_to_give_to_your_code
```

If instead it is invoked like this:

```
{*}$procname $thing_to_give_to_your_code
```

Then you *can* do it by passing in a ***command prefix***.

```
analyse_tx -proc [list bar fooshta]
```

This is the one I'd recommend. It might also work if the invoke is done like this:

```
eval $procname [list $thing_to_give_to_your_code]
```

This sort of thing is great since it also lets you pass in things like lambda terms bound to `apply` and so on. It's a very flexible system (since it actually works as a general function currying mechanism) and it's pretty simple.

However, if you're stuck with this style of invoke:

```
$procname $thing_to_give_to_your_code
```

then we have to use an indirect mechanism: an intra-interpreter ***alias*** will let us make a command (so yes, it will have a name) that delegates to the method:

```
# The {} are to indicate that this command is aliasing from and to the current interpreter context
interp alias {} delegate-bar-fooshta {} bar fooshta
```

Then we can just pass `delegate-bar-fooshta` in as the command name. If you're doing this a lot, you probably ought to put the delegates inside the object's namespace context; it's probably easiest to make a method for setting things up:

```
oo::class create foo {
   constructor {} {
      variable numy 2
   }
   method fooshta { mos_pointer } {
      puts "now in mosy [get name $mos_pointer ]"
   }
   destructor {}

   method delegate {method args} {
      # We'll also bind in any extra arguments you choose to use
      interp alias {} [self namespace]::delegate-$method \
              {} [self] $method {*}$args
      return [namespace which delegate-$method]
   }
}

foo create bar
analyse_tx -proc [bar delegate fooshta]
```

By doing it like this, killing off the object using the usual mechanisms will also remove the delegate commands that it owns. This is highly convenient in a complex program, as it offloads more of the housekeeping chores to Tcl itself from your script.

Comment: 1. wow
2. Thanks, I will ask the EDA vendor to extend the interface

Comment: Since you can make the delegate aliases easily enough, you don't need the vendor to cooperate. ;-)

Comment: I don't. But if I can make the vendor work harder, might as well... we are paying him enough.

Comment: Hi. I have been looking at the code of the alias. I do not understand why are there the {}  [ self namespace  ]  {} [self namespace]? Are they some sort of delimiters?